# How to use lift from ToFunctorOps

Tags: scala, scalaz

`ToFunctorOps` defines a `lift` method via the `ToLiftV` implicit, but I can't seem to make it find my functor instances:

```
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.functor._
import scalaz.syntax.id._
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._

def inc(x: Int) = x + 1

1.some |> (inc _).lift

<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter F: scalaz.Functor[F]
              1.some |> (inc _).lift
```

The functor instance for option is visible but the compiler can't seem to find it. Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand exactly why this isn't working (and I've just asked [a follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13515169/334519) about the part I don't understand), but I can offer three workarounds.

The [first](https://gist.github.com/4131492) makes no sense to me and requires some deeper changes to your code and clunky syntax, so I'll only mention it in passing.

The second is to import the appropriate `FunctorSyntax` implicits (as opposed to the `ToFunctorOps` ones that aren't working properly):

```
scala> val of = implicitly[scalaz.Functor[Option]]
of: scalaz.Functor[Option] = scalaz.std.OptionInstances$$anon$1@377d4c39

scala> import of.functorSyntax._
import of.functorSyntax._

scala> 1.some |> (inc _).lift
res0: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

But this requires you to import these implicits for every individual `Functor` you want to use them with, and isn't much better than just writing `of lift inc`.

The last requires a little more code but is more satisfying. You need the following new syntax trait, with a `myLift` method modeled of the `lift` in `Function2Ops`:

```
trait MyFunction1Syntax[A, R] extends scalaz.syntax.Ops[A => R] {
  def myLift[F[_]](implicit F: scalaz.Functor[F]) = F lift self
}

implicit def toMyFunction1Syntax[A, R](f: A => R) =
  new MyFunction1Syntax[A, R] { def self = f }
```

And now you can write the following:

```
scala> 1.some |> (inc _).myLift
res3: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

It might be worth bringing this issue up on the Scalaz mailing list.

Comment: I don't understand your claim on the second workaround. These imports should suffice. 'import scalaz.std.AllInstances._' and 'import scalaz.syntax.functor._'

Comment: @YoEight yep, that's the point of this question: they should, but they don't.

Comment: That is bizarre behaviour - really nice digging.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be easily resolved like this

```
import scalaz.syntax.std.option._
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.id._

implicit def liftIt[F[_], A, B](f: A => B)(implicit F: Functor[F]): F[A] => F[B] =
  F lift f

def inc(x: Int) = x + 1

2.some |> inc
```

The issue came from a `LiftV` trait used in FunctorSyntax. Frankly, I doubt it could have been useful for someone. In order to work, it has to be explicitly typed:

```
import scalaz.syntax.functor._

val f: LiftV[Option, Int, Int] = (inc _)

2.some |> f.lift
```